# In systemtap, how do I trap the return of a function in a user space process?

Tags: systemtap

The following systemtap script fails to compile:

```
probe process("myexe").function("myFun").return { print("hi mom\n") }
```

It says:

> semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'process' at
>   proxy.stp:6:7
>           source: probe process("/home/martin/experiments/systemtap/a.out").function("doSomething").return
>                         ^
>
> semantic error: process return probes not available [man
>   error::inode-uprobes] Pass 2: analysis failed.  [man error::pass2]
>   Tip: /usr/share/doc/systemtap/README.Debian should help you get
>   started.

I want to trap when the function exits, not the process.  If I remove the `.return` it compiles & runs fine.  How do I trap the function exit?

I'm on Ubuntu 13.04, Linux 3.8.0-29-generic, system tap 2.1/0.153.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `man error::inode-uprobe` man page explains.  Linux kernel versions before 3.10 lack the return-probes capability needed to make this work.  (Old RHEL kernels do have equivalent functions.)